# Sort symfony users by roles

Tags: php, sorting, symfony, user-interface

I have a user entity. It implements the basic user-interface.
I want to sort my users by roles and I don't know how to do it.

(it is for send a message for my admins only with a message entity who is targeting the user entity on a ManyToOne relation)

Comment: but how is work sorting? by name? by number of roles?

Comment: i want to find only my admins (ROLE_ADMIN) in my users entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u WHERE u.roles LIKE :role'
            )->setParameter('role', '%"ROLE_MY_ADMIN"%');

$users = $query->getResult();
```

Offload the work to your DB Server. This query shouldn't take long to return, even with 100,000+ records.

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe that:

```
// $users - users from db, collection of user entity class
$myAdmins = array();
foreach($users as $user){
    if (in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $user->getRoles())) {
      $myAdmins[] = $user;
    }
}
```

in `$myAdmins` has users with `ROLE_ADMIN` role.

Comment: if i have 123 000 users in my db this solution consumes lots of memory

Comment: ok, `roles` in db are stored as serializable string, so search by that isn't nice, solution for me is add field in user table which indicates  user has `ROLE_ADMIN` and than get all users which set this field.

Comment: this system of roles contained in arrays prevents all sorts from the database. what a shit for get admins or anybody else by roles.

Comment: if you want to make it simple, implement group and search after them, create group "Admins" and search after that group.

Comment: in this app, i dont have the permission to modify the user entity.
thank you very much